# How to extend ASPNET_ISAPI filter?

Tags: asp.net, .net, multi-tenant

Is there any way to extend standard aspnet_isapi filter?

I would like to override application management logic responsible for creating app domains and hosting environments - which is the responsibility of ApplicationManager class. The reason why I would like to extend it is to implement multi-tenancy support for my web application where multiple tenants can run in the same application. Since different tenants should be able to load different versions of the same assembly they need to be isolated in separate app domains. Therefore, there is a need to create new app domain per each tenant.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're after.  Do you want to write an IIS filter, extend the ApplicationManager class, or just have side-by-side assemblies in the GAC (or local to each web app?)

Comment: I would like to extend standard aspnet_isapi filter. Since ApplicationManager implementation is located there, probably this extension would be in this specific class. Do you know what I mean now?

Comment: "I would like to extend standard aspnet_isapi filter" -- that doesn't make sense to me, I think you mean you want to write a .net web app?  Do you have something already implemented, or do you just have an IIS server?  ApplicationManager is in the .net Hosting namespace, which doesn't exactly line up with IIS administrative tasks you may want to perform, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with that? I have a similar problem too.
As a result of investigation - i don't think it is a good (or even possible) approach to write your own ApplicationManager.
ApplicationManager deals with low-level request handling logic, while multi-tenancy stands much higher and much closer to application logic (business logic).
Take a look on creating child AppDomains approach. This may be the right way.